# Running Stata jobs on Slurm but errors: stata: command not found

Tags: stata, slurm

Here is my sbatch file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=stata_example.out
#SBATCH --error=stata_example.err
#SBATCH --nodes=1

module load stata
stata do stata_example.do
```

But it always returns with error: stata: command not found.
I have tried with "stata-mp" or "stata-se" "stata-ic",
or "stata -b stata_example.do".
but it returns same error information.
Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Try the full path of the command. You see it with `type stada`.

Comment: Is the `module load` command issue an error?

Comment: I tried adding the full path to `stata` but it returns with Exit Code 126 "Permission Denied"

Comment: I have no problem using 'module load'. I typed `module list` it will return "1) Stata"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you type in module list and Stata comes up, you may need to identify the appropriate path.

In my case, it is `module load sloan/stata/15/mp`

I would suggest you contact the administrator to find out what the appropriate path is.